# Use openCV Stitcher with Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv-stitching

I want to stitch two Images using the OpenCV-Library. Because the rest of my Code is written in Java I want to use the OpenCV JavaAPI. But I couldn't find a way to access the OpenCV Stitcher Class.

Does anyone know if there is a way to import any OpenCV class into Java? Or does the JavaAPI of OpenCV just not supply every functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found anything?